# HandlebarJS global counter

Tags: handlebars.js

I want to create a global counter which will get replaced with next value everytime it is used e.g. {{Counter}} And if I use as below in template

- This is line {{Counter}}
- This is line {{Counter}}
- This is line {{Counter}}
- This is line {{Counter}}

Then is shall render as

- This is line 1
- This is line 2
- This is line 3
- This is line 4

Is this possible through handlebarJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `HandlebarsHelper` to achieve that.

```
var temp = 1;
Handlebars.registerHelper('Counter', function() {
  return temp++;
});
```

And your Handlebars template be,

```
This is line {{Counter}}
This is line {{Counter}}
This is line {{Counter}}
This is line {{Counter}}
```

Which **outputs**

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
```

Tested using - http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Hope this helps.